# Printf does not print string properly

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i am having trouble with the following.

Since I am fairly new to C, I am not sure under what kind of words or terms I should have searched on google. So my apologies in advance.

I have simplified the programm a lot to narrow it down to the actual problem.

Here is the problem:

I allocate memory before I call the loadfile function. I pass a pointer to loadfile() and execute the code in there. Then I added a few printfs to see if the code is working as i expected.

Well its not: I would say that I set up the pointers correctly since the adresse of which the pointer in the function is poitning to and the adress of the actual struct array are the same.

However when I want to print the string item.name some strange signs are printed to the screen. printing only the first character of that string works.

Can anyone help me with that?

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "warehouse.h"


int main()
{
    int row=1, choice;
    Cars* item=(Cars*)malloc(sizeof(Cars));
    char inName[64];


do
{
        choice=printmenu();                                                     /** Print menu and ask for choice **/
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 10:                                                                /** choice 10 executes the loading function **/
            printf ("Enter name of file to be opened: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf ("%63s", inName);

            row=3;
            item=(Cars*)realloc(item,(row*sizeof(Cars)));
            loadfile(item,inName);

            printf(" adress in main1: %d \n", &item[0].artno);
            printf(" adress in main2: %d \n", &item[1].artno);
            printf(" name1 in main: %c \n", item[0].name[0]);
            printf(" name1 in main: %s \n", item[0].name);                      /*!!! printing the string has completely unexpected behavior, see screenshot !!!*/

            break;

        case 11: break;
        }

} while(choice!=11);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

loadfile.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "warehouse.h"


void loadfile(Cars *load,char inName[63])
{
    char c,cartno[10]={},camount[10]={},cprice[10]={};
    FILE *in;
    int i=0,sem=0,z=0 /*rows=0*/;

    if ( (in = fopen (inName, "r")) == NULL )                               /** if file couldn't be found, return error message and return to menu **/
    {
    printf ("Can't open %s for reading.\n", inName);
    getch();
    return 0;
    }

    while ( (c = getc (in)) != EOF )                                        /** read each character in file until end of file (EOF) is read **/
    {
    if (c!=';')                                                             /** evaluate if read character is a semicolone (semicolone separates entities in data-file **/
    {
        if (sem==0)    {   cartno[z]=c;         z++;    }                    /** all characters before the first semicolone are numbers and saved to character string cartno **/
        if (sem==1)    {   (load+i)->name[z]=c; z++;    }                   /** all characters after first and before second semicolone are saved to item.name **/
        if (sem==2)    {   camount[z]=c;        z++;    }                    /** all characters after second and before third semicolone are saved to character string camount **/
        if (sem==3)    {   cprice[z]=c;         z++;    }                    /** all characters after third and before fourth semicolone are saved to character string cprice **/
        if (sem==4)                                                         /** when fourth semicolone is reached cartno, camount and cprice is transformed to integer and floats with atoi,atof **/
        {   sem=0;
            (load+i)->artno=atoi(cartno);
            (load+i)->amount=atoi(camount);
            (load+i)->price=atof(cprice);

            i++;

            memset(cartno,0,sizeof(cartno));                                /** all positions of the temp arrays are set to zero, in case of another loop **/
            memset(camount,0,sizeof(camount));
            memset(cprice,0,sizeof(cprice));

        }
    }else              {sem++;                 z=0;    }
}

printf(" adress in loadfile1: %d \n", &(load)->artno);
printf(" adress in loadfile2: %d \n", &(load+1)->artno);
printf(" name1 in loadfile: %c \n", (load)->name[0]);
printf(" name1 in loadfile: %s \n", (load)->name);                          /*!!! printing the string has completely unexpected behavior, see screenshot !!!*/

fclose (in);
printf ("File has been loaded.\n");
return 0;
}
```

printmenu.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/** This function prints the menu **/

int printmenu()
{
    int choice;

   //system("cls");

    printf("[10]\tLoad file\n");
    printf("[11]\tQuit\n\n");

    printf("Please choose: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    return choice;

}
```

warehouse.h

```
#ifndef WAREHOUSE_H_INCLUDED
#define WAREHOUSE_H_INCLUDED

struct cars {
    int amount, artno;
    float price;
    char name[20];

};

typedef struct cars Cars;

int printmenu();
void loadfile(Cars *load,char inName[63]);

#endif // WAREHOUSE_H_INCLUDED
```

and here the file I am loading:

```
1;Bier;11;12.00;
2;Wodka;43;13.89;
3;Rum;6;29.10;
```

unfortunatly I am not allowed to upload screens jet, so I had to use an extern hoster.
http://www.imagebanana.com/view/1zisbkuf/strange.jpg

printf(" name1 in main: %s \n", item[0].name);

I expect printf to print: name1 in main: bier
But it prints strange signs.

Comment: Consider posing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Very few people will want to sift through all that code.

Comment: At least show some example incorrect output, and what you expected for the same example.

Comment: for one thing it seems odd to assume a certain size in the file before opening it `row=3` and then do a realloc, if you knew the size why do realloc? either you read the file record by record and realloc when needed or you malloc all you need at start since you already know the size.

Comment: also reconsider the use of memset, if you know the variables are temporary why not just move the declarations into the scope so that they automatically get initialized in each loop? i.e. within your while loop.

Comment: well I narrowed down the code. usually i define the number of rows with a different function, an then i allocate according to the rows determined.
true i could move the memset. havent thought about it this way.

but i am having trouble with the printf and what appears on the screen.

Comment: That's very low quality code. You are returning 0 from void function. Don't use /** comment **/ for one line comments. It's impossible to comment out multiple lines for debug purposes.

Comment: Recommend: do not mix `getc()` with `scanf()`. `scanf()` likely leaves a `\n` in `stdin` that the next `getc()` picks up.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error; you should name the compiler used. Also, the screenshot seems no longer accessible; anyway, it would be better to post the output as text (or a hexdump of it).

Answer (score 0):

Your file reading function could be a lot lot easier.
Change

```
while ( (c = getc (in)) != EOF )
{
    ...                                     
}
```

in loadfile.c to

```
char buf[256];
while (fgets(buf, 255, in)) {
    char *pch = strtok(buf, ";");
    load[i].artno=atoi(pch);

    pch = strtok(NULL, ";");
    strcpy(load[i].name, pch);

    pch = strtok(NULL, ";");
    load[i].amount = atoi(pch);

    pch = strtok(NULL, ";");
    load[i].price = atof(pch);

    i++;
}
```

It's assumes that loading file is in correct format and every entry is in a new line.

Comment: `fgets(buf, 255, in)` could instead be `fgets(buf, 256, in)` or better yet `if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, in) != NULL)`.